# Video for Windows Codec x264 and VP80

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, programming

I'm looking for VfW codec to encode H264 and VP80.

- I already found: [x264vfw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/)
- And [VP80vfw](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/VP8-VFW-Codec)

The 1st is bugged and lost the start and the end. The 2nd do not install on Windows 8.

Why VfW ? to use then in a C# sofware using EmguCV, recording frame by frame. I can't use ffmpeg.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really an alternative to x264vfw. Are you sure the error is with the codec and not your application? It's in wide use, such a major bug would definitely be found.

Also be aware that h264 doesn't work in a frame by frame basis unless you encode only intra frames.
VP80 is NOT h264, just a similar codec.

If you need to develop an app you probably want to turn to a commercial h264 implementation like MainConcepts Codec SDK: http://www.mainconcept.com/products/sdks/codec-sdk/video/h264avc.html
Should also come with a vfw codec.

Alternatively you can turn to GStreamer which offers C# bindings: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp

Another option could may be [ffdshow](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ffdshow) it adds quite a few codecs to VfW and I believe also x264.

Comment: Thanks, I have byte[]bgr image that I need to store quickly and compressed so I choose EmguCV that I already use elsewhere. As you say many codec are no free so complicated for a side project. I record 10s video and it lost 1-2s to start but it could be EmguCV indeed

Comment: GStreamer is great for developing OpenSource or even commercial apps with video functionality but its not that super duber easy to use, though if you are willing to give it a try it definitely offers great features, is pretty robust and in the end not THAT hard to use.
You could also use native C++ code in your C# app to use the latest version of GStreamer.
E: Actually it seems the continued development, the latest C# bindings are from 2014! Last time I checked the latest code was from 2009.

Comment: Indeed 2009 is 5 years ago ^^ I'll give a try to EmguCV I already use and test an other vfw FOURCC codec. Then I'll try to pay if I can